# How to cover SwiftUI Picker with a proper accessibility modifiers

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiaccessibility

I have a SwiftUI Picker:

```
Picker(selection: self.$selectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
    Text("△").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(0)
    Text("□").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(1)
    Text("○").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(2)
}.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

Want to make it accessible for VoiceOver. Tried to do the following:

```
Picker(selection: self.$selectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
    Text("△").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(0).accessibility(label: Text("Triangle label"))
    Text("□").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(1).accessibility(label: Text("Square label"))
    Text("○").font(.system(size: 20)).tag(2).accessibility(label: Text("Circle label"))
}.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

Accessibility inspector shows label="△" but I expect it should show label="Triangle label".

Please help to find out the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, I filed it with Apple as FB8806682. I noticed two interesting factors, at least on iOS 14.

1. This only happens when using the `SegmentedPickerStyle()`. A default picker will correctly read the provided labels.
2. If you *activate* any control on the screen (including the picker itself!) then the segmented picker will start reading the proper labels.

As part of the Feedback Assistant entry I created a sample app that shows the two pickers and demonstrates the difference. It's available [on GitHub](https://github.com/HiddenJester/PickerAccessibilityTesting) as well.

Comment: Great job! It really seems like that issue is a bug that needs to be fixed by Apple.